# Products not displayed

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, products-view

I have a multi-store site, and i have 2 problems :

> 1- When I create a product, I can only set the product for the
>   main-website, and not the main-website/storegroup or view I want. Only
>   one checkbox is displayed at the main-website level.
>
> 2- I am not able to display the product created above in the specified
>   category. I am sure it is set under the correct category, but
>   $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection(); is always
>   empty.

```
The product "prod1" is a "simple product". The categories are set as
following :
Products
 --> Cartes (id 34)
 -------> Cartes de visites (id 38)
```

Below the executed query when I access the category "Cartes de visites" in the frontend :

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `zoccatalog_product_entity` AS `e`  INNER JOIN `zoccatalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '38'  INNER JOIN `zoccatalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 ORDER BY `cat_index`.`position` ASC LIMIT 12;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

After digging a little bit more, i found that the table 'catalog_product_index_price' is empty. Re-Indexing wont help.

Regards.

Comment: For first part, you can set product status at the store level. Just switch the scope from top-left corner. This way you can control it at the store level. For second part, please add more information about what product setup you have done and what category structure you have.

Comment: You mean for the 1), a product is always set at creation time at the Website level, then it needs to be disabled for each store it should not be available?

Comment: When you check those checkboxes in websites tab, it means that product belongs to that website. Then, you can choose to show it in individual stores as you wish by changing it's status. It is to create a cleaner interface for what products belong to which website.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Didnt know, never dealed with multi-store. FYI, I added more info, about what I have been checking.

Comment: If you have products in that category and able to access that category from front-end(i.e. It's under the root category of that site), check if products are actually visible via direct URL. If they are, try re-indexing, if they aren't then check if something is wrong with the product itself.

Comment: I have and able to access directly that category. The prodcuct is accessible directly via url.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. If the stock_status of the products is set to out of stock even the qty is more than 0, the index wont be created. Hence, not displayed.
So setting the status to "in stock" and re-indexing fixed the issue.